# Is `"F j, Y"` an unacceptable date format for Wordpress queries?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Am I crazy? On my wordpress site, I was running a query with the dateformat of my field as `"m-d-Y"` and it all was working brilliantly. Then I decided to change the field format to `"F j, Y"` (so it's easier for me to read) and my queries stopped working. I went through and updated all of them to the new format, and they still aren't working.

Is `"F j, Y"` an unacceptable date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saving dates to the database it's best to save them in a `YYYYMMDD` format or `Ymd` if you're using `date()`, you can always convert them into a more readable form during runtime. For reference, WP_Query and `meta_values` suggest you use this format when testing Between dates:

> The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the
>   date is stored at the format YYYYMMDD and tested with this format.

[Link To Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You can view the legal parameters regarding the date and time functions of WordPress here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time and as I can see in the example, `l, F j, Y` would return "Friday, September 24, 2004", so it seems like you are using legal arguments.

Do you want to give us some more details about the problem?

Comment: I solved it by reverting to the original format the data was stored in (m-d-Y), but was perplexed as to whether there was a reason the one way worked and the other didn't.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress stores dates in the database using the format `m-d-Y`, this is why your original code worked as expected.

When you updated your code to the format `F j, Y` nothing is being returned.

Instead of querying with a different format use the wordpress functions [the_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_date) or [the_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time) to re-format your date after it is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

It's acceptable.

"F j, Y" is default date format of [the_date() function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) for wordpress.